# Installing Git SDK 64 bit - no trusted keys?

Tags: windows, git-bash

I am trying to install the Git SDK 64 bit on my Windows 10 system. I have installed it before just fine, but evidently something must have changed, so it's not working this time around. The installer's here:

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64

The problem seems (perhaps) to be no ultimately trusted key. But.. I didn't have to install any keys before. Here's a log of my install showing where it goes awry:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 git-for-windows                                 28.8 KiB   255K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 git-for-windows.sig                            543.0   B   530K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw32                                        378.5 KiB   575K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw32.sig                                     95.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw64                                        378.6 KiB  1117K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw64.sig                                     96.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 msys                                           159.8 KiB  89.2K/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 msys.sig                                        96.0   B  46.9K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) msys2-runtime-2.9.0-7

Total Download Size:   2.30 MiB
Total Installed Size:  9.90 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
warning: no /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ cache exists, creating...
:: Retrieving packages...
 msys2-runtime-2.9.0-7-x86_64                     2.3 MiB  2035K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                           [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                         [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                              [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                        [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                      [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing msys2-runtime                                           [#######################################] 100%
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) bash-4.4.012-2

Total Download Size:   1.92 MiB
Total Installed Size:  9.86 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 bash-4.4.012-2-x86_64                         1965.3 KiB  2024K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                           [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                         [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                              [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                        [#######################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                      [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing bash                                                    [#######################################] 100%
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (8) gcc-libs-6.4.0-3  gzip-1.9-1  less-529-1  libiconv-1.14-2  libintl-0.19.8.1-1  libpcre-8.40-2
             ncurses-6.1.20180210-1  info-6.3-1

Total Download Size:    3.11 MiB
Total Installed Size:  14.65 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 gcc-libs-6.4.0-3-x86_64                        820.3 KiB   934K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 ncurses-6.1.20180210-1-x86_64                 1319.8 KiB  1598K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libiconv-1.14-2-x86_64                         534.0 KiB  1428K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libintl-0.19.8.1-1-x86_64                       30.8 KiB  3.00M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libpcre-8.40-2-x86_64                           94.2 KiB  46.5K/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 less-529-1-x86_64                              105.6 KiB  2.24M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 gzip-1.9-1-x86_64                               98.7 KiB   166K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 info-6.3-1-x86_64                              178.8 KiB   627K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) checking keys in keyring                                           [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) checking package integrity                                         [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) loading package files                                              [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) checking for file conflicts                                        [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) checking available disk space                                      [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/8) installing gcc-libs                                                [#######################################] 100%
(2/8) installing ncurses                                                 [#######################################] 100%
(3/8) installing libiconv                                                [#######################################] 100%
(4/8) installing libintl                                                 [#######################################] 100%
(5/8) installing libpcre                                                 [#######################################] 100%
(6/8) installing less                                                    [#######################################] 100%
(7/8) installing gzip                                                    [#######################################] 100%
(8/8) installing info                                                    [#######################################] 100%
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (39) bzip2-1.0.6-2  ca-certificates-20170717-2  coreutils-8.26-2  findutils-4.6.0-1  gettext-0.19.8.1-1
              glib2-2.48.2-1  gmp-6.1.2-1  heimdal-libs-7.5.0-1  icu-60.2-1  libasprintf-0.19.8.1-1  libbz2-1.0.6-2
              libcrypt-2.1-1  libcurl-7.58.0-1  libedit-3.1-20170329  libexpat-2.2.5-1  libffi-3.2.1-1
              libgcrypt-1.8.1-1  libgettextpo-0.19.8.1-1  libgpg-error-1.27-1  libidn2-2.0.4-2  liblzma-5.2.3-1
              libmetalink-0.1.3-2  libnghttp2-1.30.0-1  libopenssl-1.0.2.n-5  libp11-kit-0.23.9-1  libpsl-0.19.1-1
              libreadline-7.0.003-1  libsqlite-3.19.3.0-2  libssh2-1.8.0-1  libtasn1-4.13-1  libunistring-0.9.7-2
              libxml2-2.9.7-2  libxslt-1.1.32-1  openssl-1.0.2.n-5  p11-kit-0.23.9-1  sed-4.4-2  zlib-1.2.11-1
              gnupg-1.4.22-2  msys2-keyring-r9.397a52e-1

Total Download Size:    22.40 MiB
Total Installed Size:  101.32 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 libopenssl-1.0.2.n-5-x86_64                    803.8 KiB  1831K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 openssl-1.0.2.n-5-x86_64                      1387.9 KiB  1848K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 heimdal-libs-7.5.0-1-x86_64                    709.6 KiB  1908K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libcurl-7.58.0-1-x86_64                        206.5 KiB  1299K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libbz2-1.0.6-2-x86_64                           25.3 KiB  3.54M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 bzip2-1.0.6-2-x86_64                            52.0 KiB  4.23M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 zlib-1.2.11-1-x86_64                            55.1 KiB  3.16M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 findutils-4.6.0-1-x86_64                       492.6 KiB   867K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 gmp-6.1.2-1-x86_64                             371.3 KiB   325K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 coreutils-8.26-2-x86_64                          2.3 MiB  1556K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 sed-4.4-2-x86_64                               213.2 KiB   108K/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 libffi-3.2.1-1-x86_64                           23.2 KiB  52.2K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libtasn1-4.13-1-x86_64                         106.7 KiB   368K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 icu-60.2-1-x86_64                                7.5 MiB  1634K/s 00:05 [#######################################] 100%
 libgettextpo-0.19.8.1-1-x86_64                 117.7 KiB  52.4K/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 libasprintf-0.19.8.1-1-x86_64                   16.1 KiB  7.88M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 gettext-0.19.8.1-1-x86_64                     1542.1 KiB  1136K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 liblzma-5.2.3-1-x86_64                          78.3 KiB  71.8K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libreadline-7.0.003-1-x86_64                   266.8 KiB   963K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libxml2-2.9.7-2-x86_64                         503.7 KiB  1063K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libgpg-error-1.27-1-x86_64                     115.9 KiB  94.2K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libgcrypt-1.8.1-1-x86_64                       466.0 KiB   967K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libxslt-1.1.32-1-x86_64                        139.0 KiB   129K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 glib2-2.48.2-1-x86_64                         1737.5 KiB   367K/s 00:05 [#######################################] 100%
 libp11-kit-0.23.9-1-x86_64                     150.2 KiB  1065K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 p11-kit-0.23.9-1-x86_64                        229.3 KiB   822K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 ca-certificates-20170717-2-any                 419.8 KiB   941K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libcrypt-2.1-1-x86_64                           32.1 KiB  5.23M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libedit-3.1-20170329-x86_64                     96.9 KiB  2.20M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libsqlite-3.19.3.0-2-x86_64                    564.3 KiB   184K/s 00:03 [#######################################] 100%
 libunistring-0.9.7-2-x86_64                    504.5 KiB   601K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libidn2-2.0.4-2-x86_64                          76.7 KiB  2.27M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libexpat-2.2.5-1-x86_64                         63.0 KiB  2.67M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libmetalink-0.1.3-2-x86_64                      34.7 KiB  4.84M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 libnghttp2-1.30.0-1-x86_64                      65.3 KiB  41.2K/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 libpsl-0.19.1-1-x86_64                          63.7 KiB  60.7K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libssh2-1.8.0-1-x86_64                         173.4 KiB   590K/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 gnupg-1.4.22-2-x86_64                         1038.4 KiB   872K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 msys2-keyring-r9.397a52e-1-any                  18.9 KiB  2.64M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
(39/39) checking keys in keyring                                         [#######################################] 100%
(39/39) checking package integrity                                       [#######################################] 100%
(39/39) loading package files                                            [#######################################] 100%
(39/39) checking for file conflicts                                      [#######################################] 100%
(39/39) checking available disk space                                    [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
( 1/39) installing libbz2                                                [#######################################] 100%
( 2/39) installing bzip2                                                 [#######################################] 100%
( 3/39) installing zlib                                                  [#######################################] 100%
( 4/39) installing libopenssl                                            [#######################################] 100%
( 5/39) installing openssl                                               [#######################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for openssl
    ca-certificates [pending]
    perl
( 6/39) installing findutils                                             [#######################################] 100%
( 7/39) installing gmp                                                   [#######################################] 100%
( 8/39) installing coreutils                                             [#######################################] 100%
( 9/39) installing sed                                                   [#######################################] 100%
(10/39) installing libffi                                                [#######################################] 100%
(11/39) installing libtasn1                                              [#######################################] 100%
(12/39) installing icu                                                   [#######################################] 100%
(13/39) installing libgettextpo                                          [#######################################] 100%
(14/39) installing libasprintf                                           [#######################################] 100%
(15/39) installing gettext                                               [#######################################] 100%
(16/39) installing liblzma                                               [#######################################] 100%
(17/39) installing libreadline                                           [#######################################] 100%
(18/39) installing libxml2                                               [#######################################] 100%
(19/39) installing libgpg-error                                          [#######################################] 100%
(20/39) installing libgcrypt                                             [#######################################] 100%
(21/39) installing libxslt                                               [#######################################] 100%
(22/39) installing glib2                                                 [#######################################] 100%
Optional dependencies for glib2
    gamin: for gio fam module
    python2: for gdbus-codegen and gtester-report
(23/39) installing libp11-kit                                            [#######################################] 100%
(24/39) installing p11-kit                                               [#######################################] 100%
(25/39) installing ca-certificates                                       [#######################################] 100%
(26/39) installing libcrypt                                              [#######################################] 100%
(27/39) installing libedit                                               [#######################################] 100%
(28/39) installing libsqlite                                             [#######################################] 100%
(29/39) installing heimdal-libs                                          [#######################################] 100%
(30/39) installing libunistring                                          [#######################################] 100%
(31/39) installing libidn2                                               [#######################################] 100%
(32/39) installing libexpat                                              [#######################################] 100%
(33/39) installing libmetalink                                           [#######################################] 100%
(34/39) installing libnghttp2                                            [#######################################] 100%
(35/39) installing libpsl                                                [#######################################] 100%
(36/39) installing libssh2                                               [#######################################] 100%
(37/39) installing libcurl                                               [#######################################] 100%
(38/39) installing gnupg                                                 [#######################################] 100%
gpg: /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Generating pacman keyring master key...
gpg: skipping control `%no-protection' ()
.+++++
+++++
gpg: key 1B710BBB marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: Done
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
==> Appending keys from msys2.gpg...
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
  -> Locally signing key D55E7A6D7CE9BA1587C0ACACF40D263ECA25678A...
  -> Locally signing key 123D4D51A1793859C2BE916BBBE514E53E0D0813...
  -> Locally signing key B91BCF3303284BF90CC043CA9F418C233E652008...
  -> Locally signing key 9DD0D4217D75A33B896159E6DA7EF2ABAEEA755C...
==> Importing owner trust values...
gpg: setting ownertrust to 4
gpg: setting ownertrust to 4
gpg: setting ownertrust to 4
gpg: inserting ownertrust of 4
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   4  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   4  signed:   3  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 4m, 0f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2  valid:   3  signed:   0  trust: 3-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
Optional dependencies for gnupg
    curl: gpg2keys_curl
(39/39) installing msys2-keyring                                         [#######################################] 100%
Updating keyring
==> Appending keys from msys2.gpg...
==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
  -> Locally signing key D55E7A6D7CE9BA1587C0ACACF40D263ECA25678A...
  -> Locally signing key 123D4D51A1793859C2BE916BBBE514E53E0D0813...
  -> Locally signing key B91BCF3303284BF90CC043CA9F418C233E652008...
  -> Locally signing key 9DD0D4217D75A33B896159E6DA7EF2ABAEEA755C...
==> Importing owner trust values...
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: no need for a trustdb check
==> Appending keys from git-for-windows.gpg...
==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
  -> Locally signing key 3B6D86A1BA7701CD0F23AED888138B9E1A9F3986...
==> Importing owner trust values...
gpg: inserting ownertrust of 6
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   4  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   4  signed:   3  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 4m, 0f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2  valid:   3  signed:   0  trust: 3-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) curl-7.58.0-1  pacman-mirrors-20160112-1  which-2.21-2  xz-5.2.3-1  pacman-5.0.1-5

Total Download Size:    7.89 MiB
Total Installed Size:  35.92 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'curl-7.58.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from dl.bintray.com : error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
warning: failed to retrieve some files
 pacman-mirrors-20160112-1-any                    9.2 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 which-2.21-2-x86_64                             17.2 KiB  2.80M/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 xz-5.2.3-1-x86_64                              145.4 KiB   243K/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 pacman-5.0.1-5-x86_64                            7.0 MiB  1589K/s 00:05 [#######################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) curl-7.58.0-1  pacman-mirrors-20160112-1  which-2.21-2  xz-5.2.3-1  pacman-5.0.1-5

Total Download Size:    0.71 MiB
Total Installed Size:  35.92 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'curl-7.58.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from dl.bintray.com : error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) curl-7.58.0-1  pacman-mirrors-20160112-1  which-2.21-2  xz-5.2.3-1  pacman-5.0.1-5

Total Download Size:    0.71 MiB
Total Installed Size:  35.92 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'curl-7.58.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from dl.bintray.com : error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) curl-7.58.0-1  pacman-mirrors-20160112-1  which-2.21-2  xz-5.2.3-1  pacman-5.0.1-5

Total Download Size:    0.71 MiB
Total Installed Size:  35.92 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'curl-7.58.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from dl.bintray.com : error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
Could not install pacman
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue. After some searching, I found that something like this has been asked in the repository's 'gitter' here: https://gitter.im/git-for-windows/git?at=5a7e36d518f388e626847a05

Based on that link, here is a summary of what got it working for me:

1. In your Git for Windows SDK install folder, check the size of the `usr/ssl/cert.pem` file. If it's 0 bytes, then replace it with the `cert.pem`  file from [the `usr/ssl/` directory in the in the git-sdk-64 repository](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/tree/master/usr/ssl).
2. Then check the files your install's `usr/ssl/certs/`. If either of them is 0 bytes long, then try replacing it with the corresponding files from the repo.
3. After that I ran `setup-git-sdk.bat` in the root of my Git for Windows SDK install folder, and it continued the installation (was able to get past where the above error occurred).

And as a note in case anyone wants to try fixing this bug: This happened to me after using the [`git-sdk-installer-1.0.6-64.7z.exe` release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.6).